# Can't create a zip file within a shared library for jenkins pipeline

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, antbuilder

I try to create a zip file within a shared library for jenkins pipeline with the help of `AntBuilder`. A simple zip file can be created, but as soon as I try to use a block it does not work. I don't get any error message or Exceptions. How can I debug a Pipepeline-Script? Or how can I solve the issue?

My Code looks as follow (step zipFolder doesn't work, step zipFolder2 does work)

Jenkinsfile 
    @Library('utils') _

```
pipeline {
    agent any 
    stages {
        stage('Build') { 
            steps {
                zipFolder( )
                zipFolder2( )
            }
        }

    }
}
```

shared library:

vars/zipFolder.groovy:

```
import com.example.Utilities

def call(){
  new Utilities(this).zip(pwd())
}
```

vars/zipFolder2.groovy

```
import com.example.Utilities

def call(){
  new Utilities(this).zip2(pwd())
}
```

src/com/example/Utilities.groovy

```
package com.example
import groovy.util.AntBuilder
import org.apache.tools.ant.DefaultLogger

class Utilities implements Serializable {
  def steps
  def byteStream

  Utilities(steps) {this.steps = steps}

  def zip(baseDir){
    def ant = setupAnt(baseDir)
    def destFolder = "${baseDir}/Dist"
    def destfile = "${destFolder}/test.zip"

    ant.delete dir: destFolder
    ant.mkdir(dir: destFolder)
    ant.zip(destfile: destfile, whenempty: 'create', excludes: destfile) {
      zipfileset (dir: "${baseDir}/install", includes: "test.txt",  erroronmissingdir: false)
   }

    steps.echo "Zip1"
    steps.echo "Ant-Result: " + byteStream.toString()
  }

  def zip2(baseDir){
    def ant = setupAnt(baseDir)
    def destFolder = "${baseDir}/Dist2"
    def destfile = "${destFolder}/test.zip"

    ant.delete dir: destFolder
    ant.mkdir(dir: destFolder)
    ant.zip(destfile: destfile, whenempty: 'create', excludes: destfile, basedir: baseDir)

    steps.echo "Zip2"
    steps.echo "Ant-Result: " + byteStream.toString()
  }

  def setupAnt(baseDir){
    def ant = new AntBuilder()
    byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    def printStream = new PrintStream( byteStream )
    def project = ant.project

    project.buildListeners.each {
        if ( it instanceof DefaultLogger ) {
                it.setMessageOutputLevel(org.apache.tools.ant.Project.MSG_DEBUG)
                it.setOutputPrintStream printStream
                it.setErrorPrintStream printStream
        }
    }

    ant
  }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

`AntBuilder` is not `Serializable`. What we did is encapsulate the call to AntBuilder inside an extra groovy script which is created on the fly and called by calling the groovy binary like:

```
writeFile file:createZip.groovy text:”””
def antBuilder = new AntBuilder()
...
“””
sh ‘groovy createZip.groovy’
```

You could also consider using the Jenkins Pipeline zip step. See https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#zip-create-zip-file

Answer (score 0):

With the hint of [Joerg S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4279361/joerg-s) I solved the issue with the following Code:

`src/com/example/Utilities.groovy`

```
package com.example

import org.apache.tools.ant.DefaultLogger


package com.example

import org.apache.tools.ant.DefaultLogger


class Utilities implements Serializable {
  def steps
  def byteStream

  Utilities(steps) {this.steps = steps}


  def zip(baseDir, Closure callback ){
    def ant = setupAnt()
    def destFolder = "${baseDir}/Dist"
    def destfile = "${destFolder}/test.zip"

    ant.delete dir: destFolder
    ant.mkdir(dir: destFolder)

    ant.zip(destfile: destfile, whenempty: 'create', excludes: destfile, callback)

    steps.echo "Ant-Result: " + byteStream.toString()
  }


  def setupAnt(){
    def ant = new AntBuilder()
    byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    def printStream = new PrintStream( byteStream )
    def project = ant.project

    project.buildListeners.each {
        if ( it instanceof DefaultLogger ) {
                it.setMessageOutputLevel(org.apache.tools.ant.Project.MSG_DEBUG)
                it.setOutputPrintStream printStream
                it.setErrorPrintStream printStream
        }
    }

    ant
  }


}
```

`vars/zipFolder.groovy`

```
import com.example.Utilities

def call(Closure callback){
  new Utilities(this).zip(pwd(), callback)
}
```

`Jenkinsfile`

```
@Library('utils') _

pipeline {
    agent any 
    stages {
        stage('Build') { 
            steps {
                cleanWs()
                writeFile file: 'test.txt', text: 'Sample Text'
                writeFile file: 'test2.txt', text: 'Sample Text 2'
                writeFile file: 'src/test3.txt', text: 'Sample Text 3'

                zipIt()

            }
        }

    }
}

@NonCPS
def zipIt(){
    zipFolder( ) {
        delegate.zipfileset (dir: "${pwd()}", includes: "test.txt", excludes: "src/**" , filemode: "0755", prefix: "bin/examples", erroronmissingdir: false)
        delegate.zipfileset (dir: "${pwd()}/src", includes: "*.txt",  erroronmissingdir: false)
    }
}
```

Important is the use of the annotation `@NonCPS` and `delegate.zipfileset` instead of simply using `zipfileset`.

*Edit:* This solution does not work on a slave. This code is executed at the master server, even if the build is run on a slave.